# Ideal comparator with hysteresis in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, comparator

I prepared my own ideal comparator with hysteresis and it seems this comparator doesn't work OK. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? Here is the schematic of my comparator:

[image]

When I use it in a simple circuit, the behavior is very strange:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're not showing us your entire schematic including the `.tran` command.  Anyway, I suggest looking into `tripdv` and `tripdt` for your behavioral voltage source.

Comment: Tripdv and tripdt solves the issue without slowining the simulation down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need the output to not be dependent on Vout and to be fixed, I would use V+ and V- in the if statements so the voltage output is not dependent on itself.

Comment: Ok, it make sense, but it is a comparator with hysteresis, so the output voltage has to stay on the same value when the input voltage is inside the hysteresis. So how should I tell to LTspice "stay on the current value" without the dependency that I used?

Comment: You don't really need to stay in the current value, that's not what comparators do, they go to one of the rails either negative or positive. Replace the vout with V+